# Running VirtualBox on Macbook Pro?

Tags: windows-7, mac, virtualbox, osx-mountain-lion, macbook-pro

How do I run VirtualBox on a Macbook? Is it possible, or do I need Parallels? I want to run Windows7 on my 15" macbook pro along with the original OSX Mountain Lion.

Comment: Why not try it?

Comment: I fully agree with @Karan, you should just try it next time and find out.  Generally, it is best practice on SuperUser to try to figure something out first, then if you experience trouble - post questions on how to fix it/understand where you went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

1. Installation documentation is [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch02.html#idp9197088).
2. Supported guests [include Windows 7](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#guestossupport).
3. Set up a [storage device](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#settings-storage) with Windows installation media (ISO).
4. Then boot and install.
5. Install [Guest Additions For Windows](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#additions-windows).

Answer (score 1):

https://www.virtualbox.org:

> Presently, **VirtualBox runs on** Windows, Linux, **Macintosh**, and Solaris hosts **and supports** a large number of guest operating systems including but not limited to Windows (NT 4.0, 2000, XP, Server 2003, Vista, **Windows 7**), DOS/Windows 3.x, Linux (2.4 and 2.6), Solaris and OpenSolaris, OS/2, and OpenBSD.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an Intel based Mac, yes it is possible and simple.

Just [download Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) and install.  You can then fire it up and run whatever virtualized OS you desire.